# C# TCP packets lost when using different devices but not on local machine

Tags: c#, .net

Client code that sends data:

```
public void SendPointsUpdate(string teamName, int points, bool isHidden)
    {
        if (isDebug)
            return;

        var packet = new PointsUpdatePacket(teamName, points, isHidden);

        var serializedPacket = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(packet);
        var buff = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serializedPacket);
        client.GetStream().Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
    }
```

where client is TcpClient

And Server where its received:

```
while (true)
                {

                    if (client.Connected)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (!client.GetStream().DataAvailable)
                                continue;

                            var buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                            client.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                            var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer)));
                            reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

                            var packetList = new List<Packet>();
                            try
                            {
                                while (true)
                                {
                                    if (!reader.Read())
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }

                                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                                    Packet _packet = serializer.Deserialize<Packet>(reader);

                                    packetList.Add(_packet);
                                }

                                foreach (var packet in packetList)
                                {
                                    //var packet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Packet>(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));

                                    switch (packet.PacketId)
                                    {
                                     //Do stuff
                                    }
                                }
                             }
```

where client is TcpClient

Now when its running on my local PC (both client and server) Everything works great. When I use another device some packets are lost and not executed. The client device is active all of the time and is sending the packets to the server. That is how 99% of the data transfers are taking place, from client to server. I dont understand why packets are not delivering at all.

Comment: By looking at it, my first instinct would be that you are having issues with the fact that TCP is a streaming protocol and not a packet based protocol.  At the very least your code would have issues if a "packet" was split between TCP packets, or if multiple "packet"s were combined into a single TCP packet.

Comment: For example, what would your code do if you were sent and update, and that update was serialized into 20 bytes which are then split into two separate TCP packets, so that when you call `client.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);` on the server, you get 10 of the 20 bytes the first time you call it, and the remaining 10 bytes the second time you call it?

Comment: To add to what @RobertMcKee said, I consider [Message Framing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) a must read for anyone doing TCP programming.

Comment: Just don't use your own intermediate buffer, instead pipe the NetworkStream to a JsonTextReader through a StreamReader like so: `var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(client.GetStream()));` Your intermediate buffer will contain partial JSON messages that your JsonTextReader would not be able to ingest.

Comment: Also, the reason you're seeing the problem only when communicating with another device (another network interface) is because the MTU (maximum transmission unit) is much larger for the loopback adapter (localhost) then it is for a "real" network adapter, so in the case of localhost the entire JSON message would be transferred in one frame, but with a real network interface it would get chopped up into MTU-sized chunks (typically 1500 bytes)